# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp - Neural networks - Sigmoid

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, runtime-error, exp

I am working with Neural Networks and I completed all my code and it is time to train my network and when I stated training I see the following error
[image]

**and the progress of my model stayed constant at 980/10,000**
is there any way that I can fix it.
I am following a tutorial and it is on digit_recognisation. And it worked for him so well......

and my code for the sigmoid function is just:

```
def sigmoid(z):

    return 1.0/1.0+np.exp(-z)
```

Thank You

Comment: Your network seems to diverge. What happens if `z = - 1e9`? Also your sigmoid is incorrect, missing a pair of parentheses.

Comment: it would be '0' if z is a very huge negative number

Comment: please tell me then how can I give my sigmoid function

Comment: I added parentheses they made no difference

Comment: Instead of implementing the sigmoid function yourself, you could use [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).